# Insert into join table values per each of main table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `StoreTbl` to store the Stores/Markets and this table has a Boolean field called `AvailableToAllCities`
and there is another Table called `CityTbl`
And There is a join Table between them called `StoreCityJoinTbl`

The manager asked me to remove the field `AvailableToAllCities` (or not use it anymore); So I need to insert to the join table all cities for each Store,
Can I do this without use for-loop?

Comment: Yes you can do it without a for loop.

Comment: And, in fact, you SHOULD do it without a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any kind of DDL, I've had to create my own, and used very limited data. This should, however, be enough to get you there:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO
--Sample data set up
CREATE TABLE Store (StoreID int IDENTITY(1,1), StoreName varchar(50), AvailableToAllCities bit)

CREATE TABLE City (CityID int IDENTITY(1,1), CityName varchar(50));

CREATE TABLE CityStores (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), StoreID int, CityID int)
GO

INSERT INTO City (CityName)
VALUES ('London'),('New York'),('Syndey'),('Washington'),('Paris'),('Berlin'),('Shanghai'),('Tokyo');

INSERT INTO Store (StoreName, AvailableToAllCities)
VALUES ('sdgfkljasghdbfkl',1),
       ('dsfjklgh',0),
       ('sdlafiugasdljkbfh',1),
       ('asdfhjklgasdfjkl',1),
       ('sdjlhfbvgajldavfhkl',0);

INSERT INTO CityStores (StoreID, CityID)
VALUES (2,1),(2,3),(2,6),
       (5,1),(5,2),(5,7),(5,8);
GO
--So your current data looks like this

SELECT S.StoreName, C.CityName
FROM Store S
     LEFT JOIN CityStores CS ON S.StoreID = CS.StoreID
     JOIN City C ON CS.CityID = C.CityID
                 OR S.AvailableToAllCities = 1;

GO
--And now the the solution
INSERT INTO CityStores (StoreID,CityID)
SELECT S.StoreID, C.CityID
FROM Store S
     CROSS JOIN City C
WHERE S.AvailableToAllCities = 1;
GO
--Drop the old column
ALTER TABLE Store DROP COLUMN AvailableToAllCities;

GO

--And now the new query:
SELECT S.StoreName, C.CityName
FROM Store S
     JOIN CityStores CS ON S.StoreID = CS.StoreID
     JOIN City C ON CS.CityID = C.CityID;

GO
--Clean up
DROP TABLE Store;
DROP TABLE City;
DROP TABLE CityStores;
```

Comment: So, The CROSS JOIN is the key, Thank you very much @Larnu